# Snowflake Query for Latest Snapshot From Bitemporal Data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bi-temporal, point-in-time

Given a table of data with [bitemporal modeling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitemporal_modeling) where there are 2 dates: (i) the date that the data applies to, and (ii) the datetime at which the fact is known

```
City   Temp  Date        As_of_Datetime
———    ———-  ———-        -——————-
Boston 32    2022/07/01  2022/06/28 13:23:00
Boston 31    2022/07/01  2022/06/29 13:23:00
Miami  74    2022/07/01  2022/06/28 13:23:00
Miami  75    2022/07/01  2022/06/29 13:23:00
```

**What snowflake query will give the latest snapshot of the data for each date based on the most recent As_of_Datetime?**

The expected result would be

```
City   Temp    Date
Boston 31      2022/07/01
Miami  75      2022/07/01
```

I tried using the last_value function

```
select City, Date, last_value(Temp) over (partition by City, Date order by As_of_Datetime) as Temp
from temperature_table
order by City, Date
```

but that produced duplicate rows where the same last value is repeated:

```
Boston   31    2022/07/01
Boston   31    2022/07/01
Miami    75    2022/07/01
Miami    75    2022/07/01
```

Ideally there should only be 1 row returned for each (City, Date) combo.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72532036/snowflake-query-for-latest-snapshot-from-bitemporal-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be achieved by using QUALIFY and ROW_NUMBER - partitioned by City, Date and sorted As_of_DateTime descending:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY City, Date ORDER BY As_of_DateTime DESC) = 1
```